# File doesn’t execute, shows error

Tags: equations

[image: enter link description here]

What is the problem, I an new in LaTeX.

Comment: Please, don't post images, but codes. Also, inside `\[ \]` you don't need `equation*`.

Comment: I will try this

Answer (score 2):

The environment `equation` (or `equation*`) triggers math mode. You are already in math display using `\[ ... \]`, which raises an error.

Remove `\[` before `\begin{equation*}` and `\]` after `\end{equation*}`. For instance:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```